# Crack Me 01 - Crypto Riddle

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme

This is the encrypted message:

> ```
> xy}v"|y#xu|$|&a+&y}vsa*pppp*fprppp"prpp"upppzpqppp*"vptp|at~!*+p)~yr%"&t"&y}vsa*
> ```

This is a riddle in parts, follow the instructions on the given message to get the answer.

**The Riddle:**

> First of all, Who am I?
>   I am in recommencement but not in contentment
>   I am  in detection but not in incident
>   I am  in telecommunication but not in uneconomical
>
> Second, with silver try to combine
>   I promise, it will be fine.
>
> This may seem pretty basic, like 1+1
>   You have to use some power to fire up the *V*ictory gun
>
> Save me first, then extract my heart
>   If you love me, tear me apart
>
> Paste my heart to find the treasure,
>   Where 0 and 1 come together.

**Hint 1:**

> stanza 3:
>  Maybe it's not so easy and not very prime,
>  But you can say it is the answer to everything - the value of a dime

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

> `1_4m_7h3_0n3_wh0_kn0ck5`

### Poem

The poem refers to these encoding steps (thanks @Alex for the first two):

> First of all, Who am I?
> I am in recommencement but not in contentment  
> I am in detection but not in incident  
> I am in telecommunication but not in uneconomical  
> Second, with silver try to combine  
> I promise, it will be fine.

> ROT-47. Can also be identified by the character set.

> This may seem pretty basic, like 1+1
> You have to use some power to fire up the Victory gun

> Base32. Can also be identified by the character set.

> Save me first, then extract my heart
> If you love me, tear me apart

> Bzip2 decompression. Can also be identified by the "BZ" prefix.

> Paste my heart to find the treasure,
> Where 0 and 1 come together.

> Pastebin. Can also be identified by the length of 8 and the character set.

> Final pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/ZvANtc0a
>  [Solution as CyberChef recipe](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=ROT47%2847%29From_Base32%28%27A-Z2-7%3D%27,false%29Bzip2_Decompress%28false%29Pad_lines%28%27Start%27,20,%27http://pastebin.com/%27%29&input=eHl9diJ8eSN4dXwkfCZhKyZ5fXZzYSpwcHBwKmZwcnBwcCJwcnBwInVwcHB6cHFwcHAqInZwdHB8YXR%2BISorcCl%2BeXIlIiZ0IiZ5fXZzYSo&oenc=65001%29)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

*I am in recommencement but not in contentment

I am in detection butnot in incident

I am in telecommunication but not in uneconomical*

> We are talking about letters **r**, then **o**, then **t**

*Second, with silver try to combine
I promise, it will be fine.*

> Silver's atomic number is **47**. Combined with rot, it means we have to use rot47. If I use rot47 on your initial text, it gives us IJNGQMJRIFMSMU2ZUJNGD2YAAAAY7ACAAAQACAAQFAAAKABAAAYQGAEAM2EOPYZAXOJCTQUEQUJNGD2Y

Comment: good start, i edited some of the riddle, hope it's better now

Comment: The third stanxa could refer to rot13:onfr gjb be n qvssrerag onfr flfgrz